# Como hacer foto y descripcion del sitio web para telegram y otras redes sociales

Tags: html, whatsapp, telegram, meta-tags

Quiero que cuando yo envié el enlace de mi pagina web en telegram o whatsapp se muestra un preview con la imagen y descripcion como se muestra aqui:
[image: telegram]

Pero no he logrado nada mas que esto:

[image: whatsapp]

He investigado en internet y añadí estas meta etiquetas a mi pagina web pero nada cambio

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="es_ES">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Test">
<meta property="og:description" content="Loro">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://test.loro.ec/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Loro">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://test.loro.ec/www/t/test.loro.ec/template/images/slideshow/carousel/slide2.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1920">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="518">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
```